# Twilio - Get Buttons Pushed from Call SID

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

How do I go about getting the buttons on the phone pressed all together, or for a single Gather request via the call SID?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get the numbers pressed in a call by using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) in your [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml). You can either set a number of digits that you want to receive or have users dial something like # to complete their input. You set an `action` parameter on the `<Gather>` which then gets called with all the digits the user entered as a parameter in the HTTP request called `Digits`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I'm looking for getting the buttons pressed on the phone via the call SID (So I can get the information of what has been pressed via an external program that checks the logs) that has already been gathered via the <Gather> command

Comment: Ah, you're probably going to have to save that yourself. As far as I'm aware the button presses are not saved within the call object itself.